# In Matlab, for a multiple input function, how to use a single input as multiple inputs?

Tags: matlab

I have a function that takes a variable number of inputs, say `myfun(x1,x2,x3,...)`.

Now if I have the inputs stored in a structure array S, I want to do something like
`myfun(S.x1,S.x2,...)`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first convert your structure to a cell array using [STRUCT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct2cell.html), and then use that to generate the list of multiple inputs.

```
S = struct('x1','something','x2','something else');
C = struct2cell(S);
myfun(C{:});
```

Note that the order in which the fields in `S` are defined are the order in which the inputs are passed. To check that the fields are in the proper order, you can run `fieldnames` on `S`, which returns a cell with field names corresponding to the values in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Something to add to Jonas' answer: Actually you can omit the struct and go right for the cell which is then expanded into a list for the function arguments:

```
c = {125, 3};
nthroot(c{:})
```